# Select from Dropdown in View and pass back to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model like this:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public Language PreferredLang { get; set; }
}
public class Language
{
    [Key]
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to be able to select preferred language from dropdown.

In controller I get list of languages and put it in ViewBag. In view I load this list. Then i want to save selection.

My controller:

```
public ActionResult EditProfile()
{
    List<Language> langauges =  Logic.GetAllLanguages();
    ViewBag.Languages = langauges;
    UserProfile profile = GetUserProfile();
    return View(profile);
}
```

An my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayName)
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PreferredLang, new SelectList(ViewBag.Languages, "LanguageID", "DisplayName") as SelectList)

    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

When user clicks "Save", `element` object passed to controller has `DisplayName`, but `PreferredLang` is always null. **How can I pass Language back to controller?**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProfile(UserProfile element)
{
    //save element
}
```

Comment: MVC has great support for localization, no need to write your own language selection stuff: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/05/06/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-3-days-investigation-1-day.aspx

Comment: It's not about localization, the class could be anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a ViewModel with following properties:

> UserProfileViewModel

```
public class UserProfileViewModel
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int PreferredLangID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Language> PreferredLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

> View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayName)
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PreferredLangID, new SelectList(Model.PreferredLanguages, "LanguageID", "DisplayName"))
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

> Controller

```
public ActionResult EditProfile()
{
    List<Language> languages = Logic.GetAllLanguages();
    UserProfile profile = GetUserProfile();
    var viewModel = new UserProfileViewModel
        {
            ID = profile.ID,
            DisplayName = profile.DisplayName,
            PreferredLanguages = languages
        };
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditProfile(UserProfileViewModel viewModel)
{
    List<Language> languages = Logic.GetAllLanguages();
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userProfile = new UserProfile
            {
                ID = viewModel.ID,
                DisplayName = viewModel.DisplayName,
                PreferredLang = languages.FirstOrDefault(l => l.LanguageID == viewModel.PreferredLangID)
            };
        //save element
    }
    viewModel.PreferredLanguages = languages;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: How does the DropDownFor in the cshtml know what "LanguageID" means?

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle, "LanguageID" is for the [DataValueField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.multiselectlist.datavaluefield(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList.DataValueField), it's the property of the `Language` class.

Comment: I am also doing the similar thing...Tried both via ViewBag and as you shown above but in both ways I am getting null list of values. What could be the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75284606 ?